# Highlight undeclared class properties in Netbeans 8.0

Tags: php, properties, highlight, netbeans-8

Is there some way to make Netbeans 8.0 highlight undeclared class properties? I want it to complain on cases like this one:

```
$res = myFunction($this->fooo);
```

where $this->fooo is misspelled and thus undeclared.

I couldn't find such option in *Tools>Options>Editor>Hints*.

**Edit**: added a better example.

Comment: Why would it complain when it's perfectly valid in PHP?

Comment: @JonStirling may be of the same reasons it can be configured to complain on re-assigning variable value, == vs === comparisons etc., which also is accepted in PHP but at the same time is a source of hard-to-find bugs.